# Vuex user duplicates itself instead of updating itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex

I have a table of users and a method that is responsible for storing them in the database via axios.

```
async saveUser({ commit }, user) {
            let createdUser;

            if (user.id) {
                createdUser = await http.put(`/users/${user.id}`, user);
                commit('addUser', createdUser.data);
            } else {
                createdUser = await http.post('/users', user);
                commit('addUser', createdUser.data);
            }
        },
```

Everything works fine for adding, but when editing a user, instead of updating the user, a duplicate is added with the changed data. The user with the old data only disappears when the page is refreshed.

```
 mutations: {
    addUser(state, data) {
            state.users.unshift(data);
        },
}
```

I would like to find a way to eliminate the duplication so that the user is updated immediately

Answer (score 0):

Inside your actions method try to create a method for updating. For Example

```
    mutations: {
      updateTask(state, payload) {
        let task = state.user.filter((userData) => userData.id == payload.id)[0];
        task.userId= payload.id;
      },
    }, 
    actions: {

    updateTask({ commit }, payload) {
      db.collection("userData")
        .doc({ id: payload.id })
        .update({
          userId: payload.id,
        })
        .then(() => {
          commit("updateTask", payload);
        });
    },
}
```

Make sure you pass the user id inside "payload" and update the db.collection() with your axios method. Hope you find this useful